# How to link 2 datagridviews in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 datagridviews that are Grade and Student KCPE Scores. I would like when entering the scores in KCPE Scores should display the grades and points as per in the Grade datagridview in vb.net.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, take the [tour], and read [ask]

Comment: Your question really doesn't make sense as asked but I suspect that what you're asking for is how to select a parent record in one grid and have a child grid filtered to show only children of that parent. If that is the case, [check this out](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?518065-Master-Detail-(Parent-Child)-Data-binding-(-NET-2-0-WinForms)).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of merging two datagridviews, try merging two datasource and bind it into the datagridview, actually this will be the good practice to develop application.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment rather than an answer because it doesn't really answer the question asked. It also may not be the best idea because, if we're talking about master/detail data, you're then going to end up duplicating master data and not be able to easily filter detail data.